# Microsoft outlook Fetch with a form

Tags: forms, outlook, attachment

I have a very crazy query related to the Microsoft Outlook. Is there any way to connect a form to Outlook, If suppose I want to attach a file so i will attach a file in my form, and then once i click on submit or any button then it should connect to the outlook, and outlook should open and the same attachment will appear in outlook.. Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of the Outlook.Application object, call Application.CreateItem, call MailItem.Attachments.Add, then MailItem.Display.